# Uso foreach con condicion en una vista mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tengo una vista la cual muestra en una tabla HTML los datos de un modelo con un foreach, pero necesito que el foreach tenga cierta condicion.
Los datos los obtengo desde una base de datos SQL Server y la consulta que quiero mostrar es asi:

```html
Select * from Mytable where Region in (1,2,3,4) order by fecha
```

La vista

```html
 var region = string.Empty;
if ((short)Session["Id"] == 1)
{
    region = "1,3,4,5";
}
else if ((short)Session["Id"] == 5)
{
     region = "2";
}

foreach (var item in Model.Where(i => i.MyTabla.Region in (region)).OrderByDescending(i => i.Fecha))
```

Este codigo me marca error porque la palabra in no la acepta, y porque la variable region la he declarado string pero region en mi modelo es int.

Comment: Here you have another reference about your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507827/lambda-expression-in-operator-exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `where` quedaría así:

```
.Where(i => region.Contains(i.MyTabla.Region.ToString()))
```

Ese es el equivalente a `Region in (1,2,3,4)`